# Correct way of using the --remove-files option with TAR

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, tar

What is the correct way to use the `--remove-files` option when using `tar`?

Is it...

```
tar -cfvj --remove-files archive.tar.bz2 archive/
```

Or...

```
tar -cfvj archive.tar.bz2 archive/ --remove-files
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the `-f` argument is telling `tar` you are going to speficy the file name of the archive you are acting on, I would keep the archive name right after that argument. The list of files and directories to include in the archive should come last. You can specify `--remove-files` before your other arguments like this:

```
tar --remove-files -cvfj archive.tar.bz2 archive/
```

Comment: problem with this option for me is that then I no longer get tab completion working on the files part

Comment: @iss42 That is a function of your shell's autocompletion patterns not being as smart as they should be, not of incorrect tar usage. You can fix that problem separately.

Comment: @Caleb interesting! Think the one I was using in this case was default Ubuntu setup, can you point me to more info on this?

Comment: @iss42 The thing to do is ask a question about how to fix that completion on [unix.se] and link back to it here.

Comment: Shouldn't `-cvfj` be `-cvjf` i.e. the `f` flag just before the filename?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the archive file name MUST be after the `-f` option to avoid bad interpretation and make it easier to understand.

In my scripts, I prefer to use this syntax :

```
tar -cvjf archive.tar.bz2 --remove-files archive/
```

I've only switched the `j` and `f` options and moved the `remove` before the dir to archive.
The `-c` (`--create`) is a function to create the tar file, and must be at the beginning.